# upload_max_filesize not getting updated after httpd restart

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I have a RHEL6 box with php and apache.  I want to increase my upload limit to 20MB.  I changed upload_max_filesize parameter in /etc/php.ini.  I restarted the httpd service.  But when I load the php_info() page, I still see a upload_max_filesize of 2MB (the default value).

I have SELinux enabled, but I don't see any recent "avc" entries in /var/log/audit/audit.log (though I have some from a few days ago).  Is there another .ini file I must change?  How can I get an upload_max_filesize value to stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to edit the right `php.ini` file. Run the following command to find the right config file -

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

The output will show you the `Loaded Configuration File` and modify the `upload_max_filesize` there.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I actually had a syntax error in my php.ini file and didn't know it.  Your hint above gave me the location of the error.  Now everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in your php.ini file

post_max_size = 20M, 
upload_max_filesize = 20M

=> Restart your HTTPD service

Check your upload limit now